# WebView does not react after file chooser

Tags: android, webview, onresume, onpause, filechooser

I have created a WebView, which display webpage with Input type file. But after choosing file, my webview does not react to anything, only for objects outside of webView (refresh button). How can i fix it?

The problem occurs in android 4.1.2

My code:

```
package com.gymcourses.qiteq.pai16;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    ImageView refreshBtn;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (isNetworkConnected()) Log.v("INTERNET: ", "true");
        else Log.v("INTERNET: ", "false;");

        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            refreshBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshBtn);

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            refreshBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl("http://something.com");
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
            webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());



            WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){

                @Override
                public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                    // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
                }

                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
                    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

                }

                public boolean onShowFileChooser (WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                    return false;
                }

            };

            WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    refreshBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            };

            webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
            webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.alertDialogMessage))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

    }

    public void refresh(View view){
        webView.reload();
        refreshBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Example adapt it with the new Version of API, check the new implementation of FileChooser.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
        private final static String url = "https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html";
        public static WebViewActivity _activity;
        ProgressDialog progressBar;
        ProgressBar progressBar1;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        boolean loadingFinished = true;
        boolean redirect = false;
        Menu menu;
        WebView wv;
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String TAG = "WebViewActivity";

        public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Activity _activity) {
            ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) _activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            _activity = this;
            wv = new WebView(this);
            WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            settings.setSaveFormData(true);
            settings.setSavePassword(true); // Not needed for API level 18 or greater (deprecated)
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            if (cookieManager.hasCookies()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "has cookies");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "has not cookies");
            }

            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();


            wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                            long contentLength) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                //The undocumented magic method override
                //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                    WebViewActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
                }

                // For Android > 3.x
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                    WebViewActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
                }

                // For Android > 4.1
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                    WebViewActivity.this.showAttachmentDialog(uploadMsg);
                }
            });

            this.setContentView(wv);

            if (checkInternetConnection(_activity) == true) {
                if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                    wv.loadUrl(url );
                } else

                    wv.loadUrl(url );
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK).create();
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.patientez),
    getResources().getString(R.string.chargement));
                progressBar.setCancelable(true);
                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                        if (!loadingFinished) {
                            redirect = true;
                        }
                        loadingFinished = false;
                        wv.loadUrl(urlNewString);
                        return true;
                    }

                    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                        handler.proceed();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished");
                        //CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                        if (!redirect) {
                            loadingFinished = true;
                        }
                        if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
                            //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
                            if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
                                progressBar.hide();
                            }
                        } else {
                            redirect = false;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                        loadingFinished = false;
                        progressBar.show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.configDoc);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.pro_refresh)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProActivity.class);
                                //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

        }

        // to know if upload is finished


        private void showAttachmentDialog(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            this.mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");

            this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose type of attachment"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                this.mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv.canGoBack()) {
                //if Back key pressed and webview can navigate to previous page
                wv.goBack();
                // go back to previous page
                return true;
            } else {
                finish();
                // finish the activity
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // Do Some thing Here
            // this.finish();
            super.onBackPressed();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        } }
```

Comment: It works for me, but it caused another issue. After select something in FileChooser, it doesn't upload file, just going out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your onActivityResult. the important is the call of onReceiveValue() method, you can test this with an example in githhub 
https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Kitkat-WebView.  this is an exampleFor an ActivityResult:
 private ValueCallback mFIlePathCallback;
        private ValueCallback mFIlePathCallbackLollipop;

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");

        if ((requestCode == mFilechooserResultcode) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            if ((mFIlePathCallback == null) && (mFIlePathCallbackLollipop == null)) {
                return;
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //lollipop +
                String dataString = intent.getDataString();

                if (dataString != null) {
                    Uri[] result = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    mFIlePathCallbackLollipop.onReceiveValue(result);
                    mFIlePathCallbackLollipop = null;
                }
            } else {
                //kitkat -
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mFIlePathCallback.onReceiveValue(result);
                mFIlePathCallback = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is the code that you have used to satart your ActivityFor result. for your code MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE.

Comment: @Qiteq  if you want more about StartActivityForResult http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example

Comment: okay, but it still does not react. When i back to webview in Logcat i have this one: V/StateManager: destroy. Is it important maybe?

Comment: for your callBack you use  your variable mUploadMessage?